# (Help) How to make the script below can be re run after respawn?

Tags: lua, roblox, exploit, luau

So, i am trying to make it can be re run after respawn but it does not work, i am kept
struggling.

My purpose with this script (autofarm, when the tween is done, it does waiting until respawn, when it's respawned, it does re run.)

```
local function teleport()
local teleport_table = {
    location1 = Vector3.new(-70, 69, 83), -- Starter Map 
    location2 = Vector3.new(-68, 69, 9255),  -- Tweening map until above end ches
    location3 = Vector3.new(-54, -303, 9496) --to chest
}

local tween_s = game:GetService('TweenService')
local tweeninfo1 = TweenInfo.new(1,Enum.EasingStyle.Linear)
local tweeninfo2 = TweenInfo.new(20,Enum.EasingStyle.Linear)
local tweeninfo3 = TweenInfo.new(1,Enum.EasingStyle.Linear)

local lp = game.Players.LocalPlayer

local function teleport()
  if not lp.Character or not lp.Character:FindFirstChild('HumanoidRootPart') then
    print("Player character not found")
    return
  end

    function tp3_teleport(v)
        if not teleport_table[v] then
            print("Invalid location")
            return
        end
        local cf = CFrame.new(teleport_table[v])
        local a = tween_s:Create(lp.Character.HumanoidRootPart,tweeninfo3,{CFrame=cf})
        a:Play()
        while a.PlaybackState == Enum.PlaybackState.Playing do
            wait()
        end
    end

    function tp2_teleport(v)
        if not teleport_table[v] then
            print("Invalid location")
            return
        end
        local cf = CFrame.new(teleport_table[v])
        local a = tween_s:Create(lp.Character.HumanoidRootPart,tweeninfo2,{CFrame=cf})
        a:Play()
        while a.PlaybackState == Enum.PlaybackState.Playing do
            wait()
        end
        tp3_teleport("location3")
    end

function tp1_teleport(v)
    if not teleport_table[v] then
        print("Invalid location")
        return
    end
    local cf = CFrame.new(teleport_table[v])
    local a = tween_s:Create(lp.Character.HumanoidRootPart,tweeninfo1,{CFrame=cf})
    a:Play()
    while a.PlaybackState == Enum.PlaybackState.Playing do
        wait()
    end
    tp2_teleport("location2")
end

tp1_teleport("location1")
end
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    if player == game.Players.LocalPlayer then
        teleport()
    end
end)
```

I am kept trying to make it run, but also re run after respawn when the script is done and i am kept making and asking ChatGPT which resulted helpless for me.

Answer (score 0):

Changing few last lines to this should work

```lua
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    if player == game.Players.LocalPlayer then
        teleport()
        player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function() 
            teleport() 
        end) 
    end
end)
```